# Pause and Resume navigation in Skobbler maps iOS

Tags: ios, skobbler-maps

I have integrated Skobbler SDK in my iOS application and worked on navigation functionality. I have a requirement to pause and resume the navigation. I don't find any methods to pause or resume the navigation using Skobbler-maps SDK. Is there any way we can achieve the pause and resume navigation in iOS using skobbler-maps.

Thanks in Advance.